# How to bold and italicize parts of the y label axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want the yaxis to read as **Bold**index (*B*)   i.e. part of the text that is bolded and the other italicized. I tried the following based on previous examples but get errors

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x.axis = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 50),
             y.axis = rnorm(1000, 1.2, 2))

 ggplot(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), color = "gray")+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.3, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 5,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  ylab(expression(bold(paste(Bold)))text (B))


Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  ylab(expression(bold(paste(Bold))text (B)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `plotmath`. I'm not sure if I'm completely clear for what you want in bold and italic but this should give you a framework to do what you want.
The general principles:

- bold(this text will be bold)
- italic(this text will be italic)
- `~` symbol for a space
- `*` symbol to distinguish between one expression and another without a space.
- "(" brackets in quotation marks as these are special characters

I've focused on the y axis expression in the answer to remove all the  seemingly non relevant inputs to the plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = 1))+
  theme_classic() +
  ylab(expression(bold(Bold)*index~"("*italic(B)*")"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try `bquote`.

```
p + ylab(bquote(bold(Bold)~'index (B)'))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), color = "gray")+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.3, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 5,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + geom_hline(yintercept = 1)
```